# Show that $K$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $f = x^3+x+1 \in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$. We know that $K = \mathbb{F}_2[x] / \langle f \rangle$ is a ring. I just need to show that is also a field.

Its actually the first time that I need to work with a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ and Im not sure how to show that $K$ is a field.

Comment: Do you know why it's enough to show that $f $ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$ ?

Comment: This is given as the hint for this task but Im not sure why this is enough to show.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165941/finding-a-splitting-field-of-x3-x-1-over-mathbbz-2). Indeed, $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: @Arjihad, if f is irreducible, then it is a prime element. If it is a prime element, the ideal is prime. If it is prime, it is maximal.This is true because $F_2[x]$ is an PID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One more hint*: 
The polynomial $f=x^3+x+1$ is irreducible because it is a cubic polynomial which has no root  in $\mathbf F_2$. As $\mathbf F_2[x]$ is a P.I.D., this implies the ideal $(f)$ is prime, so that $\mathbf F_2[x]/(f)$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 0):

List the conditions for a ring to be a field.

- Has multiplicative identity (namely $1$)
- Every element except $0$ has a multiplicative inverse.
- Multiplication commutes (obvious)

So the core problem is:

> $$f \text{ is irreducible over } \mathbb F \Leftrightarrow \text{All elements }p\in\mathbb F/\langle f\rangle \text{ except $0$ have inverses}.$$

See how this resembles proving that $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ forms a field ($p$ prime)? When we prove that every non-zero element in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ has an inverse, we use Bezout's identity:

> Suppose $(a,b)=1$. There exist $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ that $$ma+nb=1.$$

And the proof of *that* relies on the generalized Euclidean algorithm, which, in turn, requires division with remainder. Now we know that, in $\mathbb F_2[x]$ we can perform polynomial division analogous to division with remainder in integers. So you can generalize Bezout's identity to obtain the result.